# How to pass JWT token to socket.io swift?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

My goal is to pass the JsonWebToken to socket.io swift instance class, but I keep getting error

[image]

I keep getting that error, any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: under which function you write this code ?, error says that you can not use it under initializer as self is not available there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to create a property here (`socket`) that during the initialization should use another property. This isn't possible.

What you can do instead is create an `init` method and set the property there, e.g.

```
var socket: SocketIOClient

init() {
    self.socket = SocketIOClient( ... )
}
```

For future questions please make sure to copy the code to a question instead of posting a screenshot. It's a lot easier to help you out then ;)